# Maintain user data in form actions that encounter errors

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm a longtime ASP.net WebForms dev that's learning ASP.net Core so I apologize if there's some fundamental misunderstanding going on here.
I have a simple web application with a view that is used to edit an item from a list of items, using Razor, Bootstrap 4 and jQuery Unobtrusive Validation.

The view route: `/Edit/123` (123 is the item id)

The model:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int SomeDropDownItemId { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string SomeText { get; set; }

  public List<SelectListItem> DropDownItems { get; } = new();
}
```

The controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public IActionResult EditGet(int id, MyModel model)
{
  model.Id = id;
  model.SomeDropDownItemId = 1;
  model.SomeText = "Hello world";
  model.DropDownItems.AddRange(GetItemsFromDatabase());

  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public IActionResult EditPost(MyModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "id", model.Id } });

  string errorMessage = SaveItemToDb(model);
  if (errorMessage != null)
  {
    ViewData["Error"] = errorMessage;
    return View(model);
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Step2", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "id", model.Id } });
}
```

This setup works fine in normal conditions. However if the call to `SaveItemToDb` returns an error, the `DropDownItems` model property is lost as it's not part of the posted data. If I replace the `return View(model)` with a `RedirectToAction("Edit", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "id", model.Id } })` call, any user changes are lost as the previous model is discarded.

I understand why those things are happening, but there has to be some elegant way to preserve the user input in case of errors and return to the initial view, with its controls fully populated. I don't want to duplicate code to retrieve all of the dropdown items and other shenanigans required to build the view.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the DropDownItems are not part of the posted data, they won't be in the model in the POST handler.

In the past I've reloaded this kind of lookup data before returning the view again like:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public IActionResult EditPost(MyModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "id", model.Id } });

  string errorMessage = SaveItemToDb(model);
  if (errorMessage != null)
  {
    ViewData["Error"] = errorMessage;
    // Load lookup data to model
    model.DropDownItems.AddRange(GetItemsFromDatabase());
    return View(model);
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Step2", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "id", model.Id } });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If SaveItemToDb is the model used for verification,I suggest that you **enable client-side validation** so that the form will only **be submitted** when all the data in your form meets the requirements.

You can **[click this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#client-side-validation)** to view the solution.